# Importing Angular ECharts Into a Stackblitz 15.1 project?

Tags: javascript, angular, echarts, stackblitz, ngx-echarts

Stackblitz is now using a standalone configuration for Angular Projects and when I attempt to initialize the module for [Angular ECharts (ngx-echarts)](https://github.com/xieziyu/ngx-echarts) it produces the following error:

```
Error in src/main.ts (18:5)
Type 'ModuleWithProviders<NgxEchartsModule>' is not assignable to type 'readonly any[] | Type<any>'.
```

This is how the ngx-echarts module is initialized:

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({
      echarts: () => import('echarts'),
    }),
  ],
```

In the previous non standalone versions of Angular on Stackblitz this worked fine.

How do we call `forRoot` on modules in Stackblitz Angular 15.1 projects?

[Here's a Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5hskpt?file=src%2Fdata.service.ts,src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Added an issue to Stackblitz / Core on Github: https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/2371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/xieziyu/ngx-echarts#usage) indicates an `InjectionToken` should be provided in this case instead. The module without providers is imported separately and the config provided like so:

```
import { NgxEchartsModule, NGX_ECHARTS_CONFIG } from 'ngx-echarts';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'my-chart',
  template: `
    <div echarts [options]="chartOptions" class="demo-chart"></div>
  `,
  imports: [NgxEchartsModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NGX_ECHARTS_CONFIG,
      useFactory: () => ({ echarts: () => import('echarts') }),
    },
  ]
})
```

This method also works in `NgModule`s.

Comment: Awesome!! - Here's the Stackblitz Demo for the ECharts Documentation.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oasrxv?file=src%2Fmain.ts