# Enabling Treeshaking for ngx-echarts in angular 15

Tags: echarts, tree-shaking, angular15, angular-standalone-components, ngx-echarts

I'm trying to use treeshaking for ngx-echarts in angular 15 standalone component. I followed the docs, but treeshaking doesn't seems to work.
Can anyone help in this.

I have tried both custom build and treeshaking build suggested by the documentation provided by echarts but didn't work.

Even though I import only bar chart I could see all other chart files.

Even in webpack analyser I could see the entire echarts build.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75313222/importing-angular-echarts-into-a-stackblitz-15-1-project/75487214#75487214